# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous without using numpy

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I've been searching for a solution to this error in Python 2.7.12 but I haven't found a solution. I'm implementing k nearest neighbors. The odd thing is that all questions related with this error message are using numpy and I ain't using it in that part of code. I just use numpy to load the training set and the test samples, but after that I convert the numpy arrays to python normal lists. help please. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import operator

def main():
    #cargar datos de las clases fingers y fist
    trainingSet = loadData()
    #k neighbors
    k = 3
    #cargar los datos de test y elegir mesima muestra a clasificar
    m = 1
    newPoint = loadTestSet(m)
    kNN(trainingSet, newPoint, k)
    print classification(neighbors)

def loadData():

    trainingSet = []
    fingers = np.loadtxt('statisticsTrainingSet_0.txt', delimiter=',')
    fingersL = list(fingers)
    fist = np.loadtxt('statisticsTrainingSet_1.txt', delimiter=',')
    fistL = list(fist)

    fingersL.append ('fingers')
    fistL.append ('fist')

    trainingSet.append (fingersL)
    trainingSet.append (fistL)
    #print trainingSet
    return trainingSet

def loadTestSet(m):
    newSamples = np.loadtxt('statisticsTestSet.txt', delimiter=',')
    # mesima muestra a clasificar
    newSamplesL = list(newSamples)
    sample = newSamplesL[m-1]
    #print sample
    return sample

def kNN(trainingSet, m, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(m)-1
    for i in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = distance(m, trainingSet[i], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[i], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for j in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[j][0])

    return neighbors

def classification(neighbors):
    votes = {}
    for i in range(len(neighbors)):
        classification = neighbors[i][-1]
        if classification in votes:
            votes[classification] += 1
        else:
            votes[classification] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(votes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]

def distance(p1, p2, length):
# Euclidean Distance
    distance = 0
    for i in range (length):
        distance += pow((p1[i] - p2[i]), 2)
    rootDistance = np.sqrt(distance) 
    return rootDistance

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: Ok, there is not much sense in posting a longish piece of code without a) haveing the input data to run it locally or b) having the traceback or at least the line of code where the error is raised. Maybe you can boil it down to a smaller example. However, there is one hint which can be given directly: If your array is more than 1-dimensional, `list` will convert it to a list of arrays!

Comment: Where does the error occur?  I agree that `x.tolist()` is much better that `list(x)`.  Compare the two.